# ¿Cómo eliminar un archivo cargado en un input file?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, input-file

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Lo que quiero es que el input file se pueda eliminar el archivo cargado. Cuando cargo un archivo me muestra el nombre del archivo y me gustaría que aparezca una ***X*** al lado del nombre cuando se quiera eliminar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        Archivo <input type="file">
    </div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías añadir un botón al lado del input y con JavaScript realizar lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementById("idDelInput").value = "";
```

Answer (score 3):

Si estuviera en un `form` con un `id` fácil con javascript lo limpiarías con lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementById("tu_id").reset():
```

Ahora no sé si lo mismo sería poniendo un `id` a tu `input` con lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementById("mi_archivo").value = "";
```

Comment: Es la única forma en la que se puede? A mi no me funciona :/